# How do I escape a character in a java properties file to be able to read it in an Android build.gradle file?

Tags: java, android, gradle

```
~/.gradle/gradle.properties

com_example_storePassword=Pa$$word!
com_example_keyPassword=Pa$$word!
com_example_keyAlias=alias
com_example_storeFile=/Users/example/Documents/keystores/example/keystore
```

This build.gradle file does **not** work

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion compile_sdk

    signingConfigs {
        signing {
            storeFile file(com_example_storeFile)
            storePassword com_example_storePassword
            keyAlias com_example_keyAlias
            keyPassword com_example_keyPassword
        }
    }
}
```

The error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDevRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key example from store "/Users/example/Documents/keystores/example/keystore": Cannot recover key
```

This build.gradle file **does** work

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion compile_sdk

    signingConfigs {
        signing {
            storeFile file(com_example_storeFile)
            storePassword 'Pa$$word!'
            keyAlias com_example_keyAlias
            keyPassword 'Pa$$word!'
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like there's an issue with escaping the $ character. I can't escape this in the gradle.properties file, how can I get this to work for this situation?

Comment: How about add backslash on each $ character, like this one `Pa\$\$word!`

Comment: @AbdurRohman Nope, this still doesn't work and it's also an invalid escape for a Java properties file. I think it needs to be escaped on the build.gradle side. Thanks though.

Comment: What about `Pa\\$\\$word!` ?

Comment: How about this one `"\"Pa$$word!"\"`